# Add duplicate dataframe rows in a call to apply()

Tags: python, pandas

One of my columns is a string with separate value separated with a space. I want to create a separate row for each of these values, duplicating all the other column values. For example:

```
>> d = {'A': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Coco'],
        'B': ['X1', 'Y1 Y2', 'Z1 Z2 Z3'],
        'C': [1, 2, 3]}

>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)

>> df = df.apply(func, axis=1)

>> print df
       A   B  C
0  Alice  X1  1
1    Bob  Y1  2
2    Bob  Y2  2
3   Coco  Z1  3
4   Coco  Z2  3
5   Coco  Z3  3
```

I am a little stuck on how to write "func" efficiently (or at all honestly). As a note - I have 157 columns, so anything that requires specifying the columns names is less than ideal.

What I've got so far is printing out the correct expanded dataframes for each row, but I don't know how to consolidate the results of apply:

```
def func(x):
    bs = x.B.split(' ')

    df = pd.concat([x]*len(bs), axis=1).T.reset_index(drop=True)
    for i in range(len(bs)):
        df.ix[i, 'B'] = bs[i]

    print df
    return df
```

This results in the following error. It seems like this is some sort of issue with the dimensions (there are 157 columns and 3 new rows created from the input row) but I'm confused about what apply() does with the results, and how to fix this.

> cannot copy sequence with size 157 to array axis with dimension 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you actually need a `groupby` to do what you want to do. Using an expanded `str.split()`, followed by a `stack()` and a `join()` should give you what you want:

```
>>> tmp = df['B'].str.split(expand=True)
>>> tmp = tmp.stack().reset_index(1, drop=True)
>>> tmp.to_frame('B').join(df.drop('B', 1))
    B      A  C
0  X1  Alice  1
1  Y1    Bob  2
1  Y2    Bob  2
2  Z1   Coco  3
2  Z2   Coco  3
2  Z3   Coco  3
```

You could, of course, do all this within a function that you apply on a `groupby`, but it would be superfluous in this case.

Comment: Since the OP mentioned there were lots of columns, `df[df.columns.difference(["B"])]` or something similar might be preferable to `df[["A","C"]]`.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I modified the solution to be more friendly for large numbers of columns

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I don't really get stack and unstack yet, so I guess this will be a good opportunity to dig in a grok it. In the meantime - unfortunately this code didn't work for me. I'm using Pandas version 0.15.2 and python 2.7. I initially got an error that "expand" is an unexpected keyword. Then I removed it and got an error: "'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'"

Comment: Yes, the interface for ``str.split`` has changed in recent Pandas versions. For older versions, you can use ``str.split(return_type='frame')``